# Best practice for configuring a shared library between multiple dynamic web projects in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm using Eclipse with Tomcat 7.0 and everything is working well. I have 3 webapps I'm developing and all 3 apps use the same set of source code from the same package (e.g. com.mycompany). So far I have 3 copies of the package, one for each web app, in each respective project folder. Each web app is intended to be standalone if needed.

What is the best way of configuring Eclipse Helios to have each dynamic web project use a shared library, which is also under constant development as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can be an answer?

Link additional source

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-WorkingWithExistingLayout4.htm

Answer (score 0):

Well...it's a simple enough answer...just keep the library in a single folder and import that into your project using an absolute path...however, note that this will be a problem when you are deploying the application in a different environment...